# Extended BNF problems

Tags: syntax, grammar, bnf, ebnf

I have some question about the Extended BNF.

```
(* Extended BNF grammar *)
min = 5;
max = 10;
value = integer; (* How can I set the range rule: `min <= value <= max`? *)
```

Second question:

```
name = letter, { letter | decimal digit };
(* The common length of the comment line must be not more than 128 characters. 
But I don't know the name's length. How can I set this restriction? *)
        comment line = ';', name, ' ', 128 * [ character ], new line;
```

I've read the ISO/IEC 14977:1996(E) completely, but don't find the answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm informed, you can't do it with BNF/EBNF parser alone, but you can do it in combination with some post-processing.

The trick is to parse a text by EBNF rules without caring for constraints. Later, when you get the abstract syntax tree (AST), you use Javascript (or whatever language you use for parsing) and you walk through it, node by node, and test it for constraints.